# Is it possible to have an Android app that Replace the clock on lockscreen with my own?

Tags: java, android, flutter, system-clock

I want to code my own clock, replacing the one on the lock screen. Not to sure how to do this? I only designed app that displays data from firebase. Is there a way to display using flutter or java, information like a clock or a graph on the lock screen? I can only find examples of full screen notifications.

Answer (score 0):

nope, there is no option for that. Lock screen is a separated built-in app which can't be changed by other software

BUT you can write [own lock screen app](https://github.com/Joisar/LockScreenApp), with own clock. But remember to handle other common/important features, like validating user, showing (all/non-private) notifications, allowing 112 call etc. Lot to do